# NFS client gets permission denied error

Tags: linux, nfs

I'm trying to setup NFS between two Linux machines (embedded).

```
Foo(server) -> Bar(client)
```

I have nfs-utils (1.3.3) and the dependices installed on both machines. Here is the */etc/exports* file on Foo.

```
/public 10.0.1.0/24(rw,insecure,async,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,nohide)
```

*/public* is on the local filesystem and it's not encrypted.

```
FOO# findmnt -T /public
TARGET SOURCE      FSTYPE OPTIONS
/      ubi0:rootfs ubifs  rw,relatime
```

And starting the daemon:

```
FOO# /etc/init.d/S21-nfsd start
Mounting proc/fs/nfsd: [OK]
exportfs: /public does not support NFS export
Starting /sbin/portmap: [OK]
Starting /usr/sbin/rpc.statd: [OK]
Starting /usr/sbin/rpc.mountd: [OK]
Starting /usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd: [OK]
FOO# exportfs
/public         10.0.1.0/24
FOO# cat /proc/fs/nfs/exports
# Version 1.1
# Path Client(Flags) # IPs
```

With the above I'm not sure which to believe on if */public* is really exported.

The directory has full permissions:

```
FOO# ls -ld /public
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root           160 Jan 13  1990 /public
```

On the client I try to mount the NFS share:

```
BAR# mount -t nfs -vvvv FOO:/public /public
mount: FOO:/public failed, reason given by server: Permission denied
mount: mounting FOO:/public on /public failed: Bad file descriptor
```

I'm using the root account on both machines, and uids match:

```
FOO# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
BAR# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Kernel support is there both machines as well, FOO->kernel 2.6.35, BAR->kernel 4.1.18:

```
FOO# zcat /proc/config.gz|grep "NFS"
CONFIG_NFS_FS=y
CONFIG_NFS_V3=y
# CONFIG_NFS_V3_ACL is not set
# CONFIG_NFS_V4 is not set
CONFIG_ROOT_NFS=y
CONFIG_NFSD=y
CONFIG_NFSD_V2_ACL=y
CONFIG_NFSD_V3=y
CONFIG_NFSD_V3_ACL=y
CONFIG_NFSD_V4=y
CONFIG_NFS_ACL_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_NFS_COMMON=y

BAR# zcat /proc/config.gz | grep "NFS"
CONFIG_KERNFS=y
CONFIG_NFS_FS=y
CONFIG_NFS_V2=y
CONFIG_NFS_V3=y
CONFIG_NFS_V3_ACL=y
CONFIG_NFS_V4=y
# CONFIG_NFS_SWAP is not set
# CONFIG_NFS_V4_1 is not set
CONFIG_ROOT_NFS=y
# CONFIG_NFS_USE_LEGACY_DNS is not set
CONFIG_NFS_USE_KERNEL_DNS=y
# CONFIG_NFSD is not set
CONFIG_NFS_ACL_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_NFS_COMMON=y
```

Where is my issue? Client side? Server side?

Comment: Which kind of filesystem is `/public` on? Local? Remote? Encrypted?

Comment: It's a local filesystem, it's not encrypted.

Comment: Can you add the output of `findmnt -T /public`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Linux kernel on `FOO` is version 2.6.35 ([from late 2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel#Timeline)).  It has support for UBIFS (your filesystem on the root partition, [since kernel version 2.6.27 in 2008](https://elinux.org/UBIFS#History)), but kernel support for exporting NFS mounts off of UBIFS [was added at some point during 2016/2017](https://lwn.net/Articles/708018/).

This means that your `FOO` system won't be able to export `/public` until its kernel has been upgraded to a much later kernel, or until you move the directory to some other filesystem.